# Is there a way to just grab one subset of json data from a large text file?

Tags: python

I'm looking to pull the "name" field from a large json text file and be able to store them in another file for later, but I'm getting every piece of data that was in my previous json file albeit slightly modified. How do I make it so I only grab the data after the "name": field in my json file?

I've tried

```
names = []

with open('./out.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for name in data:
    names.append(data[name])

with open('./names.json','w') as f:
    for name in names:
        f.write('%s\r\n' % name)
```

and I'm getting my exact json file back, with no formatting and u' in front of everything, likely from the json.load(f), but I have no idea how to remedy this.

my text file is formatted like this, if it matters:

```
{
"array":[
{
  "name": "Seranul",
  "id": 5,
  "type": "Paladin",
  "itemLevel": 414,
  "icon": "Paladin-Holy",
  "total": 11107150,
  "activeTime": 2205387,
  "activeTimeReduced": 2205387
},
{
  "name": "Contherious",
  "id": 9,
  "type": "Hunter",
  "itemLevel": 412,
  "icon": "Hunter-Marksmanship",
  "total": 51102811,
  "activeTime": 2637303,
  "activeTimeReduced": 2637303
},
{
  "name": "Unicorns",
  "id": 17,
  "type": "Priest",
  "itemLevel": null,
  "icon": "Priest",
  "total": 12252005,
  "activeTime": 1768883,
  "activeTimeReduced": 1761797
},
...
}
]}
```

I'm expecting to see the corresponding data for each name field, but I'm getting my entire document back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is ignoring the structure of the JSON data. Specifically, you are iterating through the keys in the JSON dictionary, which is just `array`, and then appending the value to you `names` list. This results in the whole `array` property being put into your `names` variable.

Here is what I believe you want: iterate through the entries in `array` and and them to a list, then export that as JSON to another file.

```py
import json


names = []

with open('./out.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for entry in data["array"]:
    names.append(entry["name"])

with open('./names.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(names))
```

This will result in the following JSON in `names.json`:

```
["Seranul", "Contherious", "Unicorns"]
```